# How to find out about theBroswer in GWT

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out about the User Agent in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759321/how-to-find-out-about-the-user-agent-in-gwt)

I am trying to write browser specific code. Is there a GWT API to find out which browser the client is using?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759321/how-to-find-out-about-the-user-agent-in-gwt

Comment: Wtf?!!? This is exactly (I mean exactly...) the same question gregcase is pointing to?! Some kind of joke? If not, what you are looking for is called deffered binding (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html)

Comment: z00bs is right in both cases - you should check out the other question, but I'd recommend using Deffered Binding (that way the browser specific code gets downloaded only by the browser that *actually* uses it).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this GWT API:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Navigator.html

For instance, for Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent